# CVXPY - passing both variables and constants

Tags: python, matlab, optimization, cvxpy, cvx

I'm trying to do the following (CVX matlab code):

```
variable x(2)
minimize(norm([x;1]) + 2*max([x;0])
```

But when I try to this in python CVXPY, I get an error:

```
x = Variable(2)
norm([x, 1])
```

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not
>   'Variable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from cvxpy import *
x = Variable(2)
prob=Problem(Minimize(norm(hstack([x, 1]))))
prob.solve()
```